# Rewrite woocommerce my account, login and register url to subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, woocommerce

I have a wordpress site with woocommerce installed on it. I want to rewrite its login, register and my account urls to subdomains.
E.g.
main site: example.com
login url: account.example.com/login
register url: account.example.com/register
my account url: account.example.com/my_account

I have mapped the subdomain and currently these urls are working fine but I am facing two issues:

1. I am unable to change the default urls
2. Cookies on main domain are not working on subdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cookies I added following in my wp-config.php and it worked like a charm:

```
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'lootlo.pk');
```

For urls issue after lots of searching and not getting any proper solution I changed the urls in my themes header file and also added a 301 redirection code to redirect to subdomain if any of these urls accessed without subdomain.
I also added a code for redirecting other urls to main domain if accessed through subdomain.

I do not think its a proper solution but it is serving my purpose.